# Using visa type d can I make transit in another schengen country

Tags: schengen, airport-transfer

I have a  visa (type D) issued by Malta valid for 3 month's. As my air tiket plans I have transit in paris cdg  airport and I need to change airport to go malta .can I go out of the airport? Will the immigration police let me go out of the airport to take my new flight from paris orly airport ? pls. help me....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a long-stay visa for one Schengen country allows you to transit through one or more other Schengen countries on your way to or from the country that issued your visa -- both airside and (as you will need) landside.

The visa also allows you to *visit* other Schengen countries (that is, for more than just transiting) as long as those visits don't total more than 90 days of every 180.